# Oil g Migration Not Writing Any Queries

Tags: fuelphp

Quick Question:

When I run this ...

```
php htdocs/travel-photo/oil generate migration follow user:string pass:text name:string photo:string email:string
```

I looked at the migrations folder, this what it shows me ...

```
namespace Fuel\Migrations;

class Follow
{
public function up()
{

}

public function down()
{

}
}
```

What could be wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I Should've read the Documentation more clearly. You need to specify what action you want to do one the migration ... So from what I created:

```
php htdocs/travel-photo/oil generate migration users user:string pass:text name:string photo:string email:string
```

I need to add: oil generate migration create_users ...

```
php htdocs/travel-photo/oil generate migration create_users user:string pass:text name:string photo:string email:string
```

http://docs.fuelphp.com/packages/oil/generate.html#migrations

Answer (score 0):

I see this going in one of two ways: (i) either generate a model using oil and have the migration auto-generated, or (ii) use a magic-named migration.

For option (i), use oil generate model and the rest should be pretty obvious - oil generates the migration as well as the model.

For option (ii), the magic-name tells oil what you are trying to accomplish with the migration, so you can create tables, add columns, drop tables, or pretty much anything else supported by oil, simply by defining a name that oil can interpret as one of these operations.